# A problem on field extension and intermediate fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

The [Exercise 20.4](https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/%7Egarrett/m/algebra/Whole_with_TOC.pdf#page=270) in Paul Garrett's *Abstract Algebra* states that

> 20.4 Let $x$ be an indeterminate over a field $k$ of characteristic $p$, a prime. Show that there are only finitely-many fields between $k(x)$ and $k\left(x^{1 / p}\right)$.

From my persepective, since $x^{1 / p}$ is a root of degree $p$ polynomial $f(y)=y^p-x$ over $k(x)$, we have $[k\left(x^{1 / p}\right):k(x)]\mid p$, which means $[k\left(x^{1 / p}\right):k(x)]=p$ as $p$ is a prime. Hence there does not exist an intermediate field $L$ satisfying $k\left(x^{1 / p}\right)\supsetneq L\supsetneq k(x)$ since otherwise, $[k\left(x^{1 / p}\right):L]>1,[L:k]>1$, contradicting $p$ being a prime.

I wonder whether my result that there are no intermediate field is correct, since the original exercise only requires to prove there are finitely-many fields in between.

Comment: The essential thesis of your approach is correct, but your argument has an error. You've concluded that $k[(x^{1/p}):k(x)]$ divides $p$, but all you've actually shown is that $[k(x^{1/p}):k(x)] \leq p$. You probably want to show directly that $k[(x^{1/p}):k(x)] = p$, and you can do so by arguing that $f(y)$ is the minimal polynomial of $x^{1/p}$ over $k(x)$. (Hint: using Gauss' lemma, reduce to showing that $f(y)$ is irreducible over $k[x]$.)

Comment: I see, thanks for the correction.